# Foundation4: Joyride firing postRideCallback on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I'm using Foundation4 in tandem with CakePhp2.4 and, until now, have had no problem with this. No matter what I do, joyRide's postRide callback is being called when the page finishes loading (and won't call again when Joyride has completed).

Also, since my goal is just to fire `initialize()` (a custom function) as soon as Joyride ends, as an alternative I've tried binding event listeners to the `.joyride-close-tip` class and even custom element id's within the joyride pane, all of which are *also* being called at page load.

I've tried so many different variations on this that I can't adequately post everything I've tried, but here's my current code:

**Notes:**
1) I'm using jQuery in noConflict mode because this all being controlled by CakePhp2.4, hence, the $j prefix instead of the usual $ for jquery, 
2) I am not able to use zepto in this app (though I don't know why; nothing works if I load it, however).

My HTML:

```
<ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
    <li data-id="module-name">
        <h4>Welcome!</h4>
        <p>You're about to start the module. But first, we'll make sure you understand the interface.</p>
    </li>
                   <!--- several more <li> pairs ---->
    <li data-button="begin">
        <h4>All Set?</h4>
        <p>Click "Begin" to get started on this module!</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="appname/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appname/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="appname/js/app.js"></script> <!-- custom js functions that reply on jquery and have no collisions with Foundation -->
<script> 
    $j(document).foundation('joyride',
                            'start',
                            { postRideCallback: initialize() }
    );
    // have also tried:
    // $j(document).foundation().foundation('joyride','start',{postRideCallback: initialize()});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's reference, the problem was that I was handing an actual function to `postRideCallBack`, instead of an a function definition—ie. simply wrapping `initialize()` in `function() { initialize(); }` solved the problem.

Comment: `{ postRideCallback: initialize }` (no brackets) should have worked too.